# expression cannot be used as a function - IF STATEMENT

Tags: function, compiler-errors, expression

i am getting "expression cannot be used as a function," error when compliling this function.  All else works when this is commented out.

```
boolean feedActive = 0;
DS3231_Simple Clock;
DateTime now;
byte lights [5] {0,0,0,0,0};  //active, ontimeH, ontimeM, offtimeH, offtimeM

void runPowerSched(){

  if (feedActive == false){

     for (int x=0; x<2; x++) {

     if ((now.Hour() == lights[1+(x*2)]) && (now.Minute() == lights[2+(x*2)]) && (lights[0] == 1))
     {light_toggle(abs(x-1));}
}
```

Not sure on exactly what language this is, seems like  mixture in the other parts of the code, but all compiles within the arduino software.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  thank you!

Comment: Please tag the language, this looks like a weird mix of C (`byte[] ... {}`) and Java (`false`) ... And what is `now`?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Is there a = missing in the initialization of the lights array?

Comment: @JimmyB Not if it's C++11, then it's a valid initializer list. But C++11 doesn't have `boolean`.

Comment: i updated the OP.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in this part:

```
 if ((now.Hour() == lights[1+(x*2)]) && (now.Minute() == lights[2+(x*2)]) && (lights[0] == 1))
 {light_toggle(abs(x-1));}
```

i had to remove the () after the now.Hour, now.Minute.

works now.  Thanks for everyones help